# Binary quadratic form $f$ represents at least one integer relatively prime to a given integer $M$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, quadratic-forms

I encountered this statement on a reading on quadratic binary form.

"Let $f(x, y)$ be an arbitrary integral quadratic form, and let $M$ be an integer. Then
$f$ represents at least one integer that is relatively prime to $M$."

I can see why this statement is true when $f$ is a primitive form, but what about when f is any form?

Comment: Sure, but why does this help solve the problem? It seems to make the case worse - if M is also divided by k, then the statement is false. Thank you! @WillJagy

Comment: @WillJagy Sorry, I am still not clear. Would you mind explaining a bit?